# Evaluate multiple asserts in unit test - not stop at the first failing one

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Is it possible to ask rust to evaluate all asserts in a single unit test? Let's consider the following unit test.

```rust
#[test]
fn it_works() {
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 5);
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 6);
}
```

I would like to see that both the first and last asserts are failing. Right now, rust panics at the first one and stops evaluating remaining checks. The only solution that I came up with was to use `panic::catch_unwind`:

```rust
use std::panic;

#[test]
fn it_works2() {
    panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        assert_eq!(2 + 2, 5);
    });
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 6);
}
```

Is there the more elegant way to do it?

I understand there are different opinion about multiple asserts in a single unit test but I do not intend to weigh in on any side of that discussion, just to know how to do it in rust.

Comment: The normal way to do this (not just in Rust) is to write individual tests for that. A test should always only test one thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would write a separate test for each of them. Because usually you want *all* `assert`s to hold, and it does actually not matter very much if the first or the second failed - *all* of them must hold.

If this is not desirable, you could try to evaluate the conditions, and only have one single `assert_eq` that compares the resulting values as a tuple. You could then try to invent something that prints only differing elements.

To do that, you could do all the relevant comparisons one after another, and possibly store tuples (remembering left-hand and right-hand side) of failing comparisons in a `Vec`. At the end, you could `assert` that the `Vec` is empty. If it is not empty, you show the differences.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I wanted to know if it is possible to have multiple (more than) asserts being evaluated from purely practical perspective. When I am fixing unit test I would like to know all conditions that are not satisifed. In the end, as you said, all of them must hold. But as I understand there is not an easy solution for that in rust as of now.

Thanks for your suggestions.